# convert EST date to Unix Time Stamp in Javascript

Tags: javascript, gettime

I want to convert a date given in EST timezone to unix time stamp. I am not sure if the following lines of code gives me the unix time stamp of the EST date 2018-12-30. Can anyone please help.

`var estDate = '2018-12-30"; 
var d = new Date(estDate); 
var dUnixtime = d.getTime() ;`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Date.prototype.getUnixTime = function() { return this.getTime()/1000|0};
 if(!Date.now) Date.now = function() { return new Date(); }
 Date.time = function() { return Date.now().getUnixTime(); }

 var estDate = '2018-12-30';
 var dUnixtime = new Date(estDate).getUnixTime();
```

Comment: The above code will give me the unix time stamp in seconds instead of milliseconds. But I am confused that If I have a EST date do I directly call a getTime() on that to get the Unix time stamp or do I need to convert the EST date to UTC date first before calling the getTime() function? And what do I do if have the EST date as "2018-12-30 10:35:20"

Comment: @Amrita I have update my answer . This will convert any date to Unix Timestamp.

Comment: @Amrita: If my anwer work for you then please accept my answer